# how to make wordpress plugin from PersianWebToolkit?

Tags: plugins, datepicker

I want to create a WordPress plugin by developing [PersianWebToolkit](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/)
it's a datepicker
i just want to say i have a little knowledge in php
i saw someone who do it but i didn't know how to do it.
link of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199658/cannot-read-property-event-of-undefined/45619506#45619506)

thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need an introduction to plugin development. As in all things WordPress Development, the WordPress Codex is the first place to look.

Here is the Plugin Development information: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

But you will need some PHP programming knowledge. Here's one good place to start: https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp . And the googles have plenty of information about PHP programming and tips and sample source code.

You should develop on a non-vital site - could be a testing site on your local computer, or a testing area with a WP install on your hosting site.

Good luck!